# jQuery script rollover not compatible on iDevices

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, rollover

I have a jQuery script to manage the roll-over of my images. My script works fine on PC but unfortunately this script isn't compatible with iDevices (iPad, iPhone).

`image-normal.jpg <=> image-hover.jpg`

Can you help me please ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
    $('img.rollover').hover(function () {
      $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
      this.src = this.src.replace("-normal","-hover");
    }, function () {
      this.src = this.src.replace("-hover","-normal");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You cannot use hover on a touchscreen. Period.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function)` and `$(function)` are the same thing, not sure why you're using both of them.  See: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thank you, I'm novice in JS (and jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $('img.rollover').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(){
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
            this.src = this.src.replace("-normal","-hover");
        });

        $('img.rollover').on('mouseleave touchend', function(){
            this.src = this.src.replace("-hover","-normal");
        });
    });
});
```

You will still need to touch (click) the image on mobile as there is no hovering.

Comment: Well after testing it, I have a problem. On iDevices the buttons do not return to the "normal" state when I click on it again